# Android Device wont show up in DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb, ddms

I am new to mac and trying to use various Android devices for development. Everything was working fine till today when Android devices simply wont show up in DDMS view in eclipse. I have tried to use Terminal to look up connected Android devices using:

```
~adb devices
```

Device list comes up empty. Emulator shows up fine in the DDMS view as well as in the device list from command line.

I have tried the following:

1. Disconnected the device from the computer.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Restart the device.
4. Connected the device.
5. `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`

Nothing seems to work. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the USB debug option on the device?

Comment: Please explain the difference between "device list comes up empty" vs "device list from command line".  Also, be aware that DDMS only accesses devices through ADB.  Also your "~adb" command is faulty syntax.

Comment: adb devices, returns a list of connected Android devices and Emulators, when I type this command in Terminal, it doesn't return any devices. Even though the device is connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly ensure that your device is connected in "Charge Only" mode, so that the sd-card is not mounted on your local system while testing.

Next, if you're on Ubunutu, as mentioned on the Android Dev website [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up), you need to set up the device for development to see it in the list.

> If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules
>   file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you
>   want to use for development. In the rules file, each device
>   manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the
>   ATTR{idVendor} property.

**EDIT:** So you're on a mac, then a little lookup throws [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435031/adb-devices-list-empty-snow-leopard) up. According to the post, this was the work-around:

> ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the attached device after installing
>   EasyTether driver. Use kextload/kextunload to unload from memory the
>   EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext kernel extension manually. It is in
>   /System/Library/Extensions/

Comment: Device is in charge only and I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: @user1935235 Edited for Mac.

Comment: Thank you varevarao. Easy Tethering was the issue. Just removed it and  it solved the problem. AS I said, I am new to Mac and still learning.

Comment: Sure thing. :) Best o' luck.

Answer (score 0):

Start USB debugging(in settings>applications>developer options) on device first.

And still there is problem, try following link.
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

It helped me to detect my Micromax Canvas Hd

Comment: Can you please share the UDEV file? Actually Micromax is not listed in googles OEM list!

Comment: Yes its not listed. But I tied Motorola's "22b8" value and it worked for Micromax. Also on friends PC the idea worked. We done it for Ubuntu 32 and 64 bit

Comment: I think Micromax is quite a big company, specially here in Indian and Asian market. And a lot of my friends had the same problem. So Google should add it in the list.

Comment: Not unless thier OEM shows up the likes of Google and HTC and Motorola in your case :D

Answer (score 0):

Run any project in Emulator.While running the Project you can see the device in DDMS.