# Cannot Use Actual Devices When Testing Android Apps via Eclipse with Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

I know there are several questions like this out there, but none have solved my problem, so I'm still looking for a specific solution.

I followed [Google's instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) but it just doesn't work. I'm currently using a Mac, with Eclipse ADT and my devices are a Samsung Galaxy S4 (running Android 4.2.2) and a Motorola XOOM (running Android 4.0.4)

I plugged my devices in using a USB cord and looked at the DDMS device screen, but nothing ever showed up. I've tried the following:

- Restarted the devices.
- Restarted the computer.
- Restarted Eclipse.
- Reset adb.
- Killed adb using Terminal.
- Switched out the USB cord.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the projects (I've tried it on multiple different projects).
- Made sure Developer options was turned on.
- Made sure USB debugging was turned on.

Basically, I've tried everything that all other posts have suggested, and still, nothing shows up in my Devices tab.

What have I missed? Google's instructions made it seem like it's just plug-and-play, but I've not found that that's the case.

Comment: have you tapped 5 times on "Build Number" ?

Comment: Are you talking about tapping it 7 times to turn on developer mode? Yes, that's already been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this frustrating problem. Turns out, I had quite a unique mix of problems that were manifesting themselves at the same time:

- I was using a Samsung Galaxy S4 **AND** a MacBook Pro together. Apparently this is a really bad combination.
- At the same time, the `adb` file had been automatically moved due to an update and the computer couldn't find it.
- And, when using a Mac, I didn't know to not type just `adb` in the terminal. It's supposed to be `./adb` due to some Unix reason which I'm not familiar with.
- Lastly, since I was using EasyTether, it was further complicating the issue.

In the end, I was able to cobble together a solution by reading these:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
- https://sites.google.com/site/mootpointhero/lessons-learned/-bashadbcommandnotfoundonmac
- http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/
- [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)
- [adb devices list empty -- Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435031/adb-devices-list-empty-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this:

> ```
> 1. sudo kextunload -v /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
> 2. adb kill-server
> 3. adb start-server
> ```

helps if you have EasyTether on your OSX

You can find the adb tool in /platform-tools/.

---

Querying for Emulator/Device Instances:

> adb devices

Terminate the adb server process:

> adb kill-server

Check whether the adb server process is running and starts it, if not:

> adb start-server

---

Setting Up Eclipse IDE:

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (ADT Plugin, install from Eclipse)

Specify the location of your Android SDK directory in Eclipse:

> In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears after Eclipse restart, select **Use existing SDKs** then browse and select the location of the Android SDK

---

In order to export platform-tools (from Android SDK) to the PATH of your OSX:

> export PATH=/platform-tools/:$PATH

Comment: Hmmm. After step 1, I got "com.mobile-stream.driver.EasyTetherUSBEthernet unloaded and personalities removed." But after steps 2 and 3, I got the same result: "-bash: adb: command not found".

Comment: @user2323030 find your `adb` file (mine is at at /Users/me/Desktop/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools) and run `adb commands there`. You have to add adb to PATH variable in your OSX and then add android SDK in Eclipse configurations