# Eclipse won't recognize Android devices

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse isn't recognizing neither of my two Android phones.

I've tried updating all of the Android SDKs in eclipse as well as eclipse itself.
Both of my phones are being recognized by my Macbook and Android File Transfer works like a charm.
They are both in Developer mode with Debug turned on.
I've also tried connecting them in both MTP and PTP but eclipse still won't recognize my phones.
I get the RSA fingerprint pop-up and I press OK but nothing happens.

What could be the problem? I don't know what else to do.

Edit: Eclipse used to work the last time I used it to run Android apps (which was about three-four months ago). Now, it won't recognize my phones. Also, you can't install drivers on the Mac. According to Google, it is just supposed to work.

Edit: This is what I get for the adb devices.
Marcos-MBP:platform-tools Poloe$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached

Comment: what does the commandline tool `adb devices` say?

Comment: -bash: adb: command not found

Comment: Check this [How to set up ADB (Android Debug Bridge) in Mac OSX](http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/) - Try connecting the phone thru a powered USB Hub

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem.
Turned out it was this.

[adb devices list empty -- Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435031/adb-devices-list-empty-snow-leopard)

My phones weren't being recognized because I had EasyTether installed on my phones and on my Macbook.

According to the EasyTether website:

> **ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the attached device after installing EasyTether driver**
>
> Do not follow this advice if you are not a software developer who uses the Android SDK on Mac. Otherwise run "sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext" to unload the EasyTether driver manually. Load it again with kextload when necessary.